# Component specifications needed for a high voltage front-end

Tags: capacitor, resistors, specifications

I have an ADC here that in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads131m08.pdf?ts=1601908054524&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F#page=88) has this example application circuit for a 100 - 240 VAC front end voltage measurement.

[image]

If I was going to build this circuit, what ratings should my parts have in order to survive the high voltages?

Here is the list of the valuse and links to parts that I have chosen I think would work:

[Rv](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/V510SM7/2297435)

[Rhi](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electronic-components/ERA-3AEB304V/1465913) = 300k Ohms

[Rlo](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electronic-components/ERJ-PB3B7500V/6212741) = 750 Ohms

[Rfilt](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panasonic-electronic-components/ERA-3AEB49R9V/2026631) = 49.9 Ohms

[Cfilt](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kemet/C0603C102K3GACTU/2199717?s=N4IgTCBcDaIMIAYBsCDMcCMCwGlUHEBBOAFQFUQBdAXyA) = 1000pF Ohms

Putting aside the value and tolerances, what package should I choose for the resistor? This I think can be answered by calculating the maximum power (as higher power requires a bigger package), assuming the highest voltage we normally expect is 350V and a 900k-750 ohm voltage divider would only have 0.3mA of current going through it so its power rating can be as low as 0.1W (0.0003mAx350v =0.105W).

Can my resistor really just be a 603 package 0.1W like the one I linked?

Are those tiny packages really up to the task of high voltage mains?

Comment: It is unlikely that you will find resistor packages rated for 240VAC - just read the datasheet.. Even if you do, you still have issues such as pad distance and so on.

Comment: The resistors have a voltage rating as well. The 350V max can be divided down to 116V each for the Rhi. Add some margin, and that is the package size to choose. For the one you linked to, that'd be a 1206 package.

Comment: @WesleyLee I do acknowledge PCB placement as another problem, but that will be a problem for another day. For now im first trying to gather the appropriate parts.

Comment: @Aaron Oh so that is the reason why there 3 in series, I was wondering why there are 3 in series and not just 1 900k ohm resistor.  But wont the first resistor recieve the full 350v?

Comment: I didn't mean the placement of the components but the actual distance between pads of a 0603 footprint.

Comment: @Jakequin You need to learn about current and voltage and Ohm's Law and voltage dividers. No, the first resistor only "sees" one third of the 350V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using 0603 resistors for Rhi is probably not adequate.  For mains voltage you probably want 1210 or 2512 sizes.  Rlo, Rflt, Cflt will see much less voltage, so 0603 is probably adequate for those.

To determine the what package you need for a particular voltage you need to at least look at the following.

1. **Manufacturer Rating**.  You need to consider what the manufacturer datasheet for a particular part series says is the max operating voltage.  For example, page 1 of the Vishay CRCWe3 resistor datasheet gives the following voltage ratings for different package sizes.

https://www.vishay.com/docs/20035/dcrcwe3.pdf

- 0402 40V
- 0603 75V
- 0805 150V
- 1206 200V
- 2010 400V
- 2512 500V

2. **Certification Standards.**  You need to consider what IPC or UL standards are you trying to meet regarding creepage and clearance on the PCB.  For that you need to look at the distance between the pads in the manufacturer suggested footprint (which is also in the datasheet).  For example, page 9 of the Vishay CRCWe3 resistor datasheet gives the following clearances (dimension G) for different package sizes.

- 0402 0.45 mm, IPC2221B Table 6-1, up to 30V
- 0603 0.75 mm, IPC2221B Table 6-1, up to 150V
- 0805 1.00 mm, IPC2221B Table 6-1, up to 150V
- 1206 1.50 mm, IPC2221B Table 6-1, up to 300V
- 2010 1.70 mm, IPC2221B Table 6-1, up to 300V
- 2512 4.75 mm, IPC2221B Table 6-1, up to 500V

Consult the relevant standards for full details on spacing requirements.

You may also try online tools such as...
http://www.creepage.com/

3. **Pulsed voltage rating**.
   a. The pulsed voltage rating is usually given in the datasheet as a graph of peak voltage vs time.
   b. The pulsed rating should exceed what you expect to see following your front end transient voltage suppressor.
   c.  For example, page 5 of the CRCWe3 datasheet shows that the 2512 package can withstand a pulse of 1600V for 1ms or less.
   d.  Build in lots of margin.  Its worth the extra $0.25 to prevent someone from being injured or killed when a fault occurs.

**SEARCH TOOLS**
Some distributors such as Mouser let you select voltage rating as a criteria when searching for resistors.

https://www.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Resistors/SMD-Resistors-Chip-Resistors/Thick-Film-Resistors/_/N-7h7yz

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer is very comprehensive. I will follow your advice and build to highest spec i can go as i have the pcb space and its not that much more expensive.  I will try to use only SMD components as to lessen the area of high voltage to one side of the board only making the other side safer.

Comment: Quick question, Assuming that i use that part or any part that is rated to (500v) can i now simplify the 3 series Rhi resistors into 1 900k ?

Comment: @Jakequin You can use as single 500V part as long as you don't have any certification requirements that prevent it.  For example, if a certification agency requires safety even in the event of a single faulty component then you may be required to use two resistors.  But sometimes (even in safety critical applications) the agencies allow you to treat resistors as infallible and not subject to that rule, so it depends.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rv is NTC, use Through Hole NTC, With a voltage rating of 400V.
2. Use Rhi SMD 2512 1W for safety reasons.
3. You can Use Rfilt and Clift 0603 as voltage has dropped to a safe level there.

Comment: Does Rv has to be through hole ? i would like to keep the bottom section of the pcb free from anything

Comment: In that case use SMD NTC with a 400V rating, you will find it easily on a local or online store.

Comment: Yes i did find a lot, i was just curious if through hole has some niche advantage over SMD